# Colour Plotly table based on value with index

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe

[image]

How do I plot this as Plotly table, color its cells based on the cell value, were 1 should be replaced with green color and 0 with grey.
Also while plotting the table, the column names and row index should be maintained in table without color.

The resultant table should be

[image]

Above visualization can be achieved using pandas style configurations, but how do I achieve the same in Plotly-Dash

The examples provided here https://plotly.com/python/table/#cell-color-based-on-variable,
dont show how to preserve the row and column index names/values without coloring them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's really included in [plotly table pandas](https://plotly.com/python/table/#use-a-pandas-dataframe) documentation
- just need to extend to include index in data that is provided to *header** and **cells**
- plus a simple colour matrix which matches your styling requirements

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{"index": [f"a{i+1}" for i in range(3)]},
        **{
            d: np.random.randint(0, 2, 3)
            for d in pd.date_range("18-jul-2021", periods=4)
        },
    }
).set_index("index")

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Table(
        header={"values": [df.index.name] + df.columns.tolist()},
        cells=dict(
            values=df.reset_index().T.values,
            fill_color=np.select(
                [df.reset_index().T.values == 1, df.reset_index().T.values == 0],
                ["green", "red"],
                "white",
            ),
            align="center",
        ),
    )
)
fig
```

[image]